# How can I highlight the current row in Excel 365?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am currently working with Excel files with a lot of rows / columns. It is hard to see in which row I am as the change in gray is too subtle.

Is it possible to get a border around the current line + change the background color of the header cell?
So if I'm in cell E4, I want all cells in line 5 to have a thick lower / upper border and cell E1 to temporarily change the background color.

Just changing the background color in all cells does not work for me as the background color is already used for important information.

Comment: mayb3 this is helpful: https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/3500-excel-highlight-selected-row-conditional-formatting.html

Answer (score 0):

You can press <kbd>Shift</kbd> +  <kbd>Space Bar</kbd> to select the current row.